# How to enable incoming and outgoing world wide web traffic in IIS

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, asp.net-mvc, cloud-hosting, google-compute-engine

**Goal:** Access website hosted on a remote cloud's IIS via web-browser.

**Case:** I wanted to open my IIS server (*Windows server 2012 virtual machine hosted on Google compute engine*) so that the website running **locally** on it becomes accessible via WWW.

As per [EdSf's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884163/how-to-access-asp-net-website-hosted-in-google-cloud-windows-instance?noredirect=1#comment51692903_31884163) I need to make some firewall changes initially. So

- I have enabled [WWW firewall settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238830/how-to-enable-world-wide-services-http-in-the-firewall-using-command-line)

[image: Internal traffic is enabled]

But when I go to that Virtual machine's [external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#externaladdresses), the website is not loading.

**Update:** Tried [allowing remote connections in IIS](http://weblogs.asp.net/kiyoshi/allowing-remote-connection-in-iis-on-windows-8) and I believe this opened IIS to WWW.

The binding config for the site looks like this:

[image: IIS binding config]

## I have enabled both 80 and 443 ports

Now it's running [fine on SSL port 443](https://nerdspal.com/) (*except it lacks a SSL certificate*). I am unable to access it through [http port 80](http://nerdspal.com/)

[image: site not loading]

As per [Kamran's](https://serverfault.com/users/281482/kamran) comment, I have checked the firewall rules and there seems to be the issue:

[image: Http traffic not allowed]

The http traffic doesn't seems to be allowed.

How do I change it?

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of your IIS binding config for the site?

Comment: Hi @Taz - what is IIS binding config?

Comment: What Taz is getting at is to check if you have properly setup the web application in IIS (app pool, hostname, IP bindings, etc.).....

Comment: @xameeramir - In IIS select the site in the tree on the left and screenshot the whole thing (you can blur some information if needed). We can go from there.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall setting on that cloud server? Maybe you are blocked by firewall.

Comment: I have set enabled http and https.

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: Wow!! You are a **Google guy** ;) Nice initiative!!

Comment: Can you verify if your HTTP service is accessible internally from the Windows? Is the port 80 for TCP protocol opened in the GCE firewall and allowed from any source (0.0.0.0/0)?

Comment: @Kamran - It doesn't seems to be opened. I have updated my question.

Comment: @student it looks like you were able to resolve your issue, as I was able to access the link that you provided in your question. Is it possible to post the answer so other people can benefit from it

Comment: @George - I've posted the answer

Answer (score 1):

[image: To do]

[courtesy](https://blogs.sch.gr/news/archives/390)

I'm writing this post to jot down all the things I need to do during [cloudy](https://cloud.google.com/) ASP.NET website deployments.

- Get the [database connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)
- **Re-*Publish*** project
- Grab that awesome [URL rewrite module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620654/500-19-internal-server-error-the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-t/25317499#25317499)
- Set [IIS_IUSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620654/500-19-internal-server-error-the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-t/18621550#18621550) and [app pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334216/iis7-permissions-overview-applicationpoolidentity/7334485#7334485) free
- Check that your application pool refers to correct version of .NET
- Get [re-certified](https://in.godaddy.com/help/request-an-ssl-certificate-562) - obviously it's a new server, right?
- [Import](https://support.microsoft.com/hub/4338813/windows-help#1TC=windows-7) and [install](https://in.godaddy.com/help/ssl-certificates-1000006) certificate
- Import the same in [IIS](https://nl.godaddy.com/help/handmatig-een-ssl-certificaat-op-mijn-iis-8-server-installeren-4951)

[source](https://blog.nordible.com/site-pre-requisites/)